# DataGridView CellValueChanged event will not trigger

Tags: c#, datagridview, eventhandler

Im trying to make use of the CellValueChanged event with a datagridview. I basically coppied the example from MSDN but still the event will not trigger what am I doing wrong here?

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void DataWayPoints_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateRouteList();
    }

    private void UpdateRouteList()
    {
        //TODO
    }
```

Do I need to add something or change a property in my datagridview? Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you show your XAML too?

Comment: Can you also show how/where you have assigned the EventHandler to the DataGridView, please?

Comment: I found it, as JayV mentioned I should have assigned the EventHandler Ahhh I feel a shame sorry for stealing your time guys, anyhow thanks a lot for the help